# Artillery: Load JSON document from CSV file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, artillery

My lambda function which I want to test expects a complex json and as per my understanding json needs to go into the csv file. My problem is I have tried various ways to load the json from csv but keep getting errors. I am not sure if this is even possible in Artillery. My sample csv looks like this.

**post-data.csv**

column1
{ "profile":{"name":"irfan","email":"irfan@email.com"},"address":["address1","address2"]}
{ "profile":{"name":"Tomas","email":"tomas@email.com"},"address":["address1","address2"]}
{ "profile":{"name":"Joel","email":"joel@email.com"},"address":["address1","address2"]}

I only have one column because all I want is this json document to get passed as request body to my hello world lambda so I could load test it.

Here is the contents of my Artillery script file.

```
config:
  target: "https://api-gateway-load-testing-tst-ap-southeast-2.xxxxxxxxxxx.com"
  phases:
    - 
      duration: 5
      arrivalRate: 1
  defaults:
    headers:
      x-api-key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
  payload:
    # path is relative to the location of the test script
    path: "post-data.csv"
    fields:
      - "column1"
    order: sequence
    delimiter: "~"
    skipHeader: true
    cast: false
  plugins:
    cloudwatch:
      namespace: "serverless-artillery-loadtest"
scenarios:
  - flow:
      - post:
          url: "/v1/hello-world"
          json:
            data: {{ column1 }}
```

When I put double quotes around keys and values in the json I get error saying "Error executing task: ERROR exception encountered while executing load from 1579692773908 in 1579692773908: Artillery exited with non-zero code:"

Is there any way to load the json from csv in a way that my hello world lambda function receive request body as json in the following format:

{ "data": { "profile":{"name":"irfan","email":"irfan@email.com"},"address":["address1","address2"]}}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get around this issue myself by writing custom JavaScript to load json payload instead of from a csv file. I used config.processor along with beforeScenario hook to define the my custom logic.

For anyone who may be facing the similar problem, here is my solution:

**script.yml**

```
config:
  target: "https://api-ap-southeast-2.aws.my-domain.com"
  processor: "./post-body.js"
  # Following phases test a scenario where 0 tps ramps up to 50 tps in 1 minutes, and then ramps up to 1000 tps every 30 seconds in 50 tps increment

  phases:
    - 
      duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 10
      rampTo: 50
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 50
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 100
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 150
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 200
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 250
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 300
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 350
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 400
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 450
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 500
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 550
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 600
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 650
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 700
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 750
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 800
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 850
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 900
    -
      duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 950
    -
      duration: 270
      arrivalRate: 1000
  defaults:
    headers:
      x-api-key: "fake-x-api-key"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
  plugins:
    cloudwatch:
      namespace: "my-service-name"
    influxdb:
      testName: "my-service Load Test Results"
      influx:
        host: "fake-ip-address"
        username: "fake-username"
        password: "fake-password"
        database: "influx"

scenarios:
  - name: my-service-name load test with varying load
    beforeScenario: generatePostBody
    flow:
      - post:
          url: "/my-fake-endpoint"
          json:
            "{{ data }}"
```

Following post-body.js contains my custom JS logic. I have introduced a new txt file post-data.txt which essentially replaces csv file which I mentioned in the question to host thousands of rows where each row is a request payload as json. Every time a scenario is executed, a random json payload string is picked up, converted to json object and sent as part of POST request. I am also using CloudWatch and InfluxDB to output the results.

**post-body.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const filePath = "./post-data.txt";
let postData;

/**
 * Generates post body
 */
const generatePostBody = async (userContext, events, done) => {
  try{
    // add variables to virtual user's context:
    if(postData === undefined || postData === null || postData.length === 0) {
      postData = await loadDataFromTxt(filePath);
    }
    const postBodyStr = postData[Math.floor(Math.random()*postData.length)];
    userContext.vars.data = JSON.parse(postBodyStr);

    // continue with executing the scenario:
    return done();

  } catch(err) {
    console.log(`Error occurred in function generatePostBody. Detail: ${err}`);
    throw(err);
  }
}

/**
 * Loads post body from csv file
 * @param {object} filePath - The path of csv file
 */
const loadDataFromCsv = async filePath => {
  const data = [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .pipe(csv({delimiter: '||'}))
      .on("data", data => data.push(data))
      .on("end", () => {
        return resolve(data);
      })
      .on("error", error => {
        return reject(error);
      });
  });
};

/**
 * Loads post body from text file
 * @param {object} filePath - The path of text file
 */
const loadDataFromTxt = async (path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data.toString().split("\n"));
    });
  });
}

// Load data from txt file once at the start of the execution
// and save the results in a global variable
(async () => {
  try {
  postData = await loadDataFromTxt(filePath);
  //console.log(JSON.parse(postData[0]));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error occurred in main. Detail: ${err}`);
  }
})();

module.exports.generatePostBody = generatePostBody;
```

**post-data.txt**

```
{ "profile":{"name":"irfan","email":"irfan@email.com"},"address":["address1","address2"]}
{ "profile":{"name":"Tomas","email":"tomas@email.com"},"address":["address1","address2"]}
{ "profile":{"name":"Joel","email":"joel@email.com"},"address":["address1","address2"]}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post an additional solution that worked for me and will work if your JSON is fairly simple. The problem is around quotes and commas in the CSV file when assigning JSON into a field. I changed the CSV delimiter from a comma to '|'. I also changed the JSON double quotes to single quotes to avoid being misinterpreted as start / end of CSV string. A line of my CSV data looks like this:

```
||A|B|0.5|1.5|C|[{'timeIncrement':2, 'percentSlip': 0}]
```

Then in the processor for my scenario, I simply replace all single quotes with double quotes before parsing the JSON field.

```
  var paymentScheduleReqs = context.vars.paymentScheduleReqs.replaceAll("'", '"');
  var paymentScheduleReqsInstance = JSON.parse(paymentScheduleReqs);
```

Here's the config for the CSV file:

```
  processor: "./api-payment-test-helper.js"
  payload:
    # path is relative to the location of the test script
    path: "comprehensive.csv"
    delimiter: "|"
    fields:
      - "field1"
      - "field2"
      - "field3"
      - "field4"
      - "field5"
      - "field6"
      - "field7"
      - "paymentScheduleReqs"
```

I'll be the first to admit it's kludgy, but it was simple enough and got the job done. If you have legitimate single quotes or pipes in your JSON then you'll need to deal with that.